# Jquery ajax done and fail not fireing

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have the following ajax call:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
          $( "#fform" ).submit(function( event ) {
          //alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
          event.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "apply.php",
              data: "email="+$("#emaill").val()
            })
              .done(function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
              }).fail(function()  {
                    alert("Sorry. Server unavailable. ");
                });
            });
    });
```

and in apply.php:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("some_server","some_usename","some_pass","some_db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$r=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO some_table (email, join_date) VALUES ('".$_POST['email']."', CURDATE() )");

 if($r)
{
echo 'true';
 }
else
{
echo 'false';
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

The wierd thing is that I get the email in the DB but I'm not getting any alert! please help!

UPDATE:

The form:

```
<form  method="POST" id="fform" >
            <fieldset class="clearfixx" style="width: 552px; height: 40px;">
                <div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfixx" style="width: 552px; height: 42px; top: 0px;">
                    <input placeholder="Email Address" type="email" id="emaill" name="email" class="textt" style="top: 0px; left: 58px; width: 520px; font-size: 15px; height: 38px; padding-left: 11px; padding-right: 11px; lineheight: 15px;" required>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" class="lp-element lp-pom-button" id="lp-pom-button-25" value="Submit dude"/>
        </form>
```

I get the data on DB after clicking the submit button but I don't get any alerts. Thank you

UPDATE 2:

error: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'done'

SOLVED

I was using an old version of JQuery thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the ajax function will only work if the form #fform is submitted.

put a submit button in your form:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

clicking on the submit button should trigger your function

http://jsfiddle.net/Ashkanvb/4HpG5/

Comment: Thank you I copied the code from a bigger chunk. I updated to the whole script I have

Comment: Thank you I updated my question please take a look too :) Thank you so much for your help

Comment: but it works fine have a look at fiddle link that I have added to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a little mistake in your jQuery AJAX call, try this :

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "apply.php",
         data: "email="+$("#emaill").val()
      }).done(function( msg ) {
         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      }).fail(function()  {
         alert("Sorry. Server unavailable. ");
      });
```

I suggest you to use a debug tool like firebug or the chrome developper tool, which permit to easily detect this kind of syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you I copied the code from a bigger chunk. I updated to the whole script I have